# Is there a sharia punishment for spying on another Muslim's home to inspect for homosexuality?

Tags: sharia, punishment, homosexuality

Recently when I was studying about Sharia punishment for homosexuality I came to know from few Muslims (like Tariq Ramadan, Hamza Yusuf) Sharia doesn't punish you for what you do in the privacy of your home unless you are compromising the security of the state.

I was really fascinated by this balanced viewpoint. But it may happen few people are disclosing other Muslim's sin (which doesn't have any need to be disclosed by just spying on them and complaining about them to the state and also providing witnesses).

In that scenario is there any punishment in sharia for spying unnecessarily?

Answer (score 1):

> It is also narrated in al-Saheehayn from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘**Beware of
>   suspicion, for suspicion is the falsest of speech**. Do not eavesdrop;
>   do not spy on one another; do not envy one another; do not forsake one
>   another; do not hate one another. Be, O slaves of Allaah, brothers.”

Although it is discouraged to be suspicious of your brothers and sisters, there is no punishment if you spy based on your suspicions, and then report your findings to the state if a crime was committed.

That being said, this is deeply discourage by the prophet to maintain unity and trust. For example if someone is accused of thieving, it is encouraged to find an alternative explanation that will spare that person (just as you would find excuses and alternative explanations for your own biological brother). This is to build trust and brotherhood, today we don't have this, we haven't had it for over a century, I guess this is the punishment from Allah (swt). fragmentation of the Ummah.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that leads to something haram is haram. Spying and peeking could lead to adultery and fitnah.

If the punishment is not defined in Al Quran, then the government is responsible for defining the punishment.

There was once a man who spied on rasulullah house, and rasulullah told him.

> "If I know that you peeked, I would have stabbed your eye with this iron comb".

Based on this hadith, it is allowed for us to stab the eye to those who spied on us.

Comment: You need anger management. Your comment is filled with emotion. You may or may not kill your brother, but your shouting is enough to make your brother scared. If you yell at me like that, of course I will be thinking that you're intent to kill me.

Your comment didn't really make sense on the context. How come your anger with your brother have anything to do with spying?

I am your brother in religion, you should not say anyone stupid, especially your brother, or wanted to kill him.

Comment: I'm sorry brother, I apologize sincerely for my rough attitude. Usual answers I find on this site sometimes make me lose my temper. I am extremely sorry for that.

Comment: How will you react when someone spies on you? Of course you will get angry. Since our prophet (s.a.w.) was a human being maybe he was little bit angry finding that man spying on him. That's why he said that he would poke him in the eye as stated in the hadith you mentioned. Does that give us the right to poke anyone in the eye with a sharp iron whoever take a peek in our home? It didn't seem sensible to me. Did our prophet(s.a.w.) tell us to lose common sense? Didn't he lell us not to be obsessed with religion but learn from it?

Comment: It is sensible, it is common sense. Door were made so you go straight to it, and not seeing through closed window.